# How can I compute the result of the magnitude of edges of an square image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-image, sobel

if I have an image with 11x11 pixels and In the center of the image is a square of 5x5 pixels. The gray level of the background is 0 and the gray level of the square is 50. How can I compute the result of the magnitude of edges given by the compass operator for this image taking into account that the image is not noisy? I have the code but I don't know how to apply the math on paper...

```
from skimage import filters
import numpy as np
grad_x = filters.sobel_h(input_image)
grad_y = filters.sobel_v(input_image)
edge_magnitude = np.sqrt(grad_x**2+grad_y**2)
```

Comment: Please provide a proper *"Minimal Complete Verifiable Example"* with your expected answer. You can create your input image with `I = np.zeros((11,11),np.uint8)` and `I[3:8,3:8] = 50`

Comment: @MarkSetchell so how can I apply this math on paper?

Comment: Not sure whether you are asking a programming question or a practical image filtering question, nor whether you want (or know) the answer or the method. Anyway, if you want to see visually how you do the maths for Sobel filtering, have a look here for a worked example https://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't manage to compute it :( I'm still trying to find a way to compute it on paper...And nobody seems to help me :(

Comment: It should be very simple to see how to do it if you go to the website I suggested and select the Sobel filter then mouse over any pixel to see the corresponding maths.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It didn't help me so much...